# Time Complexity of this Word Break DFS + Memorization solution

Tags: algorithm, word-break

when dealing with wordBreak problem, I found this solution is really concise. But not sure about the time complexity. anyone can help?

my  understanding is worst case, O(n*k), n is the size of the wordDict, and k is the length of the String.

```
class Solution {
    public boolean wordBreak(String s, List<String> wordDict) {
        return wordBreak(s, wordDict, new HashMap<String, Boolean>());
    }
    
    private boolean wordBreak(String s, List<String> wordDict, Map<String, Boolean> memo) {
        if (s == null) return false;
        
        if (s.isEmpty()) return true;
        
        if (memo.containsKey(s)) return memo.get(s);
        
        for (String dict : wordDict) { //number of words O(n)
                            //startsWith is bounded by the length of dict word, avg is O(m), can be ignored
                            //substring is bounded by the length of dict word, avg is O(k), k is the length of s
                            //wordBreak will be executed k/m times, k is the length of s, worse case k times... when a single letter is in the dict
            if (s.startsWith(dict) && wordBreak(s.substring(dict.length()), wordDict, memo)) {
                memo.put(s, true);
                return true;
            } 
        }
        memo.put(s, false);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's worse than O(nk) for several reasons:

1. You ignore "m", but `m` is Omega(log k). (Because k < |A|^(m+1) where |A| is the size of your alphabet).
2. `s.substring` is probably O(n). Your code looks like Java, and it's O(n) in Java.
3. Even if `s.substring` were linear, Your Map requires the string to be hashed, so your map operations are O(n) (where note carefully -- `n` is the size of the string rather than the size of the hashtable like it would normally be).

Probably this means you have complexity O(n^2k*logk).

You can fix 3 easily -- you can use `s.length` rather than `s` as the key to your hashtable.

Problem 2 is easy but slightly annoying to fix -- rather than slicing your string, you can use a variable that indexes into the string. You probably have to re-write `startsWith` yourself to using this index (or use a trie -- see below). If your programming language has an O(1) slice operation (for example, `string_view` in C++) then you could use that instead.

Problem 1 is only theoretical, since for real word lists, m is really small compared to either the length of the dictionary or the potential length of input strings.

Note that using a trie for the dictionary rather than a word list is likely to result in a huge time improvement, with realistic examples being linear excluding dictionary construction (although worst-case examples where the dictionary and input strings are chosen maliciously will be O(nk)).